# Why doesn't your stipend increase after your courses are complete?

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, funding, salary

A big argument I hear for why stipends are actually a great deal is because tuition is covered(often).

This makes sense for the first year or two but once courses are complete it's no longer a valid argument. Why doesn't your stipend jump in value in accordance with what tuition would normally be valued at? I personally never even used university equipment during my time as a graduate student nor did I go to campus once I completed my courses.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you provide more value to the university after course completion? Asking for a friend.

Comment: Why do you think graduate tuition ceases when you stop taking classes? It doesn’t at many places.

Comment: There are assets on campus more valuable than equipment.  One hopes.

Comment: The real answer is university accounting is made up and has little connection to reality and is designed to be as advantageous for the institution as possible with no regard to individuals.

Comment: @Buffy absolutely, you both have greater technical skills and you're spending more time on the problem you're working on.

Comment: I think you'll find that on paper, your dissertation research credits cost the same as an equivalent number of credits of regular courses.

Answer (score 6):

Typically the funding for tuition waivers and the funding from the stipend come from separate pools of money. This is true of my current institution.

This arrangement makes more sense for the student. If instead we take the total amount given to the student in stipends and tuition waivers and distribute it equally across the student’s whole time in the programme, for the first couple of years the student will be in terrible financial hardship because they have to pay for tuition. I think most students would prefer a reasonable financial situation throughout the whole programme, rather than starvation wages in the beginning and a windfall at the end.

Comment: Not the case for mine.

Comment: @FourierFlux is the second part of my answer helpful for you nevertheless? That is is more helpful for the student to receive equal stipends throughout the whole course of study, than a tiny stipend in the beginning and a large stipend at the end

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your base premise, that tuition waivers represent some kind of significant income for a graduate student or an actual cost for having a graduate student around, isn't right (US perspective).

In STEM disciplines where a typical PhD student is a teaching or research assistant, the University is getting some value from the student as an employee. This is the extent of the financial relationship between the two. Mentoring, teaching, etc. do cost something for Universities to maintain, but then again any other viable business hiring junior employees must also maintain some of this infrastructure.

A "tuition waiver" is pure administrative fiction. The nominal amount cited isn't computed to represent actual costs to the University that they "miss out on". It's instead whatever maximum amount they can justify to external funding bodies like the NSF, which direct taxpayer dollars of this amount to the University for fellowship recipients. Every grad student doesn't cost Harvard 5 times what it costs a big state school to take on.

Comment: The thing is I know for a fact it is taken into account, for example an in state student costs a professors less at my university. As an RA my perspective is basically, if I spend X amount of time working on an NSF project I should be paid X amount of hours at least, once classes are done time spent increases and tuition costs are no longer valid expenses for the university.

Comment: @FourierFlux Right, so notice that this is still an internal accounting gimmick and really doesn't interact with you as the employee directly. Surely if you're discussing compensation, the raw number on a "tuition waiver" is totally useless for figuring that out as an employee. But I'd say it's reasonable to be convinced that PhD students are underpaid for their work, harder to argue that the underpayment is a result of administrators "misunderstanding" the value of the work or "mis-administering" salaries.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some fundamental cultural/geographic assumptions underlying your question, I will tackle your question from the US perspective where someone enrolled in an university is a customer of a for-profit cultural industry (the university itself).

> I personally never even used university equipment during my time as a
> graduate student nor did I go to campus once I completed my courses.

It really depends on your specific university. Ask them. There are universities where tuition fees are higher if you are enrolled in let's say pharmacy instead of philosophy, because the expected usage of lab&co is higher.

In general, it is the same philosophical question as paying taxes for the maintenance of roads, even if you do not own a car and you only live on your privat ranch while working remotely. You pay for infrastructures that are used by you,directly or indirectly.

You may not have been to the campus, but your instructors are having their offices there, they are using the campus infrastructure (labs, libraries, servers and networks) to provide *you* a good service.

If you feel the cost/quality ratio is too high, leave them a feedback on Google Maps.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question as you are getting measurably less value once your classes are done.

Comment: You still want your instructor and advisors to be top-notch even after your classes are finished. University equipment and campus infrastructures are need to perform research, as well, and they are at your disposal, you are free not to use them, but you are expected to take advantage of them.
On top of that, if you still need time to graduate after your classes are finished, it can be put in the bin "your fault, be quick". If you really don't need university infrastructure to conclude your studies, why don't you ask the dean for an exception, asking to have your final graduation much earlier?

Comment: Another way to look at this is that while you may make more or less use of what is on offer to you at different times in your degree, the tuition fee is calibrated to cover those costs amortised across the whole period of your degree. The other this to account for is that one hour of your supervisors time costs many times more than one hour of class. If a class has 20 students in it, then a one hour meeting once a week costs ~ 20x more than a one hour class. Whether or not you use the benefits offered is not the university's problem.